# Why $http.delete in angularJS does not work?

Tags: javascript, python, angularjs, django

I try use $http.delete with Django and get HTTP 403.
My JS file below:

```
   var myApp = angular.module('myApp',['ui.bootstrap']);

    myApp.run(function($http) {
        $http.defaults.headers.post['X-CSRFToken'] = $.cookie('csrftoken');
    });


    myApp.controller('PostsListController', ['$scope','$http',function($scope,$http) {
      $http.get('/api/v1/posts/').success(function (data) {

      $scope.posts = data;

      });
    $scope.deletePost = function(post) {
                $http.delete('/api/v1/posts/'+ post.id + '/');
    };

    }]);
```

detail from console:

```
{detail: "CSRF Failed: CSRF token missing or incorrect."}
detail
:
"CSRF Failed: CSRF token missing or incorrect."
```

Comment: Check your CSRF Token. It might not be set in the cookie.

Comment: Are you sure the cookie exists and is being set?

Comment: I know that the problem in token, but I do not know what value to set

Comment: Not sure this is an angular question then. IE: Your title is misleading.

Comment: The Django documentation provides more information on retrieving the CSRF token and sending it in ajax requests. The CSRF token is saved as a cookie called `csrftoken` that you can retrieve from a HTTP response, which varies depending on the language that is being used.. More: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/csrf/#ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i solved my problem by rewriting method .run()

```
 myApp.run(function($http) {
  $http.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken';
$http.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRFToken';
});
```